# How to ouput the continuous stream to a txt file in linux

Tags: linux, bash, centos

I have the command which continuosly outputs something on the screen of putty like we have when we install something.

Now that process is very long and its going to take many hours.
I have few questions

1. How can i output the data in text file not on screen. i tried `comand > my.txt` but it display on screen not in that file
2. Is there any way that if the file length or size increases then all previous data is emptied so that i can have only few pages only

Comment: Is it possible that you are trying to log error messages? Try `2>` instead of `>` then.

Comment: they are different level of messages like DEBUG , warning error , critical as per application

Comment: You should give more information about the specific programs that don't work as expected. Does `>` work normally? You should also split the question as the first one is totally unrelated to the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The classic solution is

```
  nohup command > my.txt 2>&1 &
```

then logout.
Sometime later, to see how it is getting on

```
  tail -f my.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Incase if you want your logfile to be rotated periodically based on size you can use "logrotate".
It can compress, rotate and even send you the compressed logs via email.

also if you are interested in doing things more perfectly use "logger" (syslog tool) for logging.

logger + logrotate is a good combination for handling logs..